# How to pull column name into a new column based on column contents in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr, purrr

I need to do three actions:

**1. Count the rowwise non NA's values in a table and sum them (in a single column "check_na")**

[I put my solution to this below, interested if someone can figure out how to do this with map though. I have already checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680413/count-na-in-given-columns-by-rows for answers for this]

**2. For those values that are not NA, create a column that concatenates these the *unique* values in a new column "block detail".**

[I don't know how to do this]

**3. If "check_na" has a value then pull in the column name(s) and concatenate them in a new column ("block type")**

[I don't know how to do this]

This is what the final product should look like.
note that in line 2 even though "b" appears twice, it only shows up once in "block detail" yet the columns that have it are individually listed "y|z"

```
      w x     y     z     na_check block_detail block_type
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int> <chr>        <chr>     
1    NA a     NA    NA           1 a            x         
2    NA NA    b     b            2 b            y|z       
3    NA NA    b     c            2 b|c          y|z       
4    NA NA    NA    NA           0 NA           NA        
5    NA NA    NA    b            1 b            z
```

below is sample data and my solution to part 1:

```
#sample data
df <- tibble(w=rep(NA_real_,5),
       x=c(1,rep(NA_real_,4)),
       y=c(NA_real_,1,rep(NA_real_,3)),
       z=c(NA_real_,1,rep(NA_real_,2),1)
       )

#my solution to the first part, interested if someone can do this more efficiently or can do this with map as I have 100s columns that I need to do this with

df_na_check <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                list(na_check=~!is.na(.)),
                .names="{.col}_{.fn}")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
mutate(na_check=sum(c_across(contains("na_check")))) %>% 
  select(w:z,na_check)
```

I appreciate any help. Ideally if the solution can use tidyverse but open to other methods (data.table or base r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can first use `rowSums` to get the number of columns that are not `NA`. Then, we can use `purrr` to collapse the unique characters that are no `NA` into `block_detail`. Then, we can use `apply` to go over each row to get the column names where there is not an `NA` for `block_type`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(na_check = rowSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = T),
         block_detail = pmap_chr(select(., -na_check), ~paste0(unique(na.omit(c(...))), collapse = "|")),
         block_type = apply(df, 1, \(x) paste0(names(df)[which(!is.na(x))], collapse = "|")))
```

**Output**

```
   w    x    y    z na_check block_detail block_type
1 NA    a <NA> <NA>        1            a          x
2 NA <NA>    b    b        2            b        y|z
3 NA <NA>    b    c        2          b|c        y|z
4 NA <NA> <NA> <NA>        0                        
5 NA <NA> <NA>    b        1            b          z
```

Or using `purrr` instead of `apply`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(na_check = rowSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = T),
         block_detail = pmap_chr(select(., -na_check), ~str_c(unique(na.omit(c(...))), collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  mutate(block_type = pmap_chr(select(., -c(na_check, block_detail)), ~str_c(names(c(...))[!is.na(c(...))], collapse="|")))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(w = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c("a", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), y = c(NA, "b", "b", NA, NA), z = c(NA, "b", "c", NA, 
"b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: this is very helpful! a few questions for you:
the block_detail column, why is the c(...) needed vs. na.omit(.)? is it because you are passing along to it a series of arguments? It is the first time I've seen the `c(...)` in a map function vs. the traditional .,.x,..1.

Answer (score 2):

This answer mainly uses `apply` to go through the dataframe row-wise, and finally use `unite` to combine colnames that is not `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(na_check = apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))),
         across(-na_check, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), NA, cur_column()), .names = "{.col}_colname"),
         block_detail = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(unique(na.omit(x)), collapse = '|'))) %>% 
  unite(col = "block_type", ends_with("_colname"), na.rm = T, sep = "|")

   w    x    y    z na_check block_type block_detail
1 NA    a <NA> <NA>        1          x            a
2 NA <NA>    b    b        2        y|z            b
3 NA <NA>    b    c        2        y|z          b|c
4 NA <NA> <NA> <NA>        0                        
5 NA <NA> <NA>    b        1          z            b
```

#### Data

Credit to @AndrewGB for the `dput` +1!

```
df <- structure(list(w = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c("a", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), y = c(NA, "b", "b", NA, NA), z = c(NA, "b", "c", NA, 
"b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combination of `mutate` and `unite`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(na_check = rowSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = T)) %>% 
  unite("block_detail", w:z, na.rm = TRUE, sep = "|", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(block_detail, na_check), ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(block_type, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = '|') %>% 
  relocate(block_detail, .after = na_check)
```

```
     w    x    y    z na_check block_detail block_type
1 <NA>    a <NA> <NA>        1            a          x
2 <NA> <NA>    b    b        2          b|b        y|z
3 <NA> <NA>    b    c        2          b|c        y|z
4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>        0                        
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>    b        1            b          z
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(w = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), x = c("a", NA, NA, NA, NA), y = c(NA, 
"b", "b", NA, NA), z = c(NA, "b", "c", NA, "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(w=rep(NA_real_,5),
             x=c("a",rep(NA_character_,4)),
             y=c(NA_character_, "b", "b", NA_character_, NA_character_),
             z=c(NA_character_, "b", "c", NA_character_, "b"))

paste_no_na <- function(x){
    x <- unique(x)
    paste0(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = "|")
}

df_summary <- df %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number(),
           w = as.character(w)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>% 
    mutate(name = if_else(is.na(value), NA_character_, name)) %>% 
    group_by(row) %>% 
    summarize(na_check = sum(!is.na(value)),
              block_detail = paste_no_na(value),
              block_type = paste_no_na(name))

cbind(df, df_summary %>% select(-row))
```

The basic idea is to pivot longer so that we can then analyze each group (ie original row) and then summarize.  If you have many rows, the performance might become poor.  Check if this is the case for you.